# Hide blue commit button in VSCode Source Control view

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to hide the large blue "Commit" button that was recently added in the VSCode Source Control view? It feels visually cluttered to me and I'm already used to using the various options under the `...` right above it anyways.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This button was added in the June 2022 release. You can alter its behavior or hide it
completely with the `git.showActionButton` or `scm.showActionButton` settings, per the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_commit-action-button-for-git-repositories). You can also type "action button" into the settings pane and alter its behavior there:

```
"git.showActionButton": {
    "commit": false,
    "publish": false,
    "sync": false
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there also a way to hide the commit message input?

Comment: @GregTomasik `"git.showCommitInput": false`